# Point chart - two (or more) data rows

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, deneb

I would like to add the average Y-axis values for each X-axis value to a point chart. Is there any way to do this please? I would like to achieve a similar result to the second picture.

[image]

Expected result is here.
[image]

**Data example**

| id | datum | year | month | day | weekday | hour | hourly_steps | cumulative_daily_steps | daily_steps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 17 | 49 | 49 | 5837 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 18 | 4977 | 5026 | 5837 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 19 | 692 | 5718 | 5837 |
| 4 | 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 20 | 13 | 5731 | 5837 |
| 5 | 2021-01-01 | 2021 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 22 | 106 | 5837 | 5837 |
| 6 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 6 | 48 | 48 | 7965 |
| 7 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 9 | 97 | 145 | 7965 |
| 8 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 10 | 1109 | 1254 | 7965 |
| 9 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 11 | 253 | 1507 | 7965 |
| 10 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 12 | 126 | 1633 | 7965 |
| 11 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 13 | 51 | 1684 | 7965 |
| 12 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 14 | 690 | 2374 | 7965 |
| 13 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 15 | 3690 | 6064 | 7965 |
| 14 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 16 | 956 | 7020 | 7965 |
| 15 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 17 | 667 | 7687 | 7965 |
| 16 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 18 | 36 | 7723 | 7965 |
| 17 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 19 | 45 | 7768 | 7965 |
| 18 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 20 | 38 | 7806 | 7965 |
| 19 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 21 | 47 | 7853 | 7965 |
| 20 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 22 | 15 | 7868 | 7965 |
| 21 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 23 | 97 | 7965 | 7965 |
| 22 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 0 | 147 | 147 | 8007 |
| 23 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 7 | 15 | 162 | 8007 |
| 24 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 8 | 54 | 216 | 8007 |
| 25 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 9 | 47 | 263 | 8007 |
| 26 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 10 | 16 | 279 | 8007 |
| 27 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 11 | 16 | 295 | 8007 |
| 28 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 12 | 61 | 356 | 8007 |
| 29 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 13 | 1459 | 1815 | 8007 |
| 30 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 14 | 2869 | 4684 | 8007 |
| 31 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 15 | 2670 | 7354 | 8007 |
| 32 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 16 | 131 | 7485 | 8007 |
| 33 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 17 | 67 | 7552 | 8007 |
| 34 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 18 | 27 | 7579 | 8007 |
| 35 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 19 | 50 | 7629 | 8007 |
| 36 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 20 | 48 | 7677 | 8007 |
| 37 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 22 | 119 | 7796 | 8007 |
| 38 | 2021-01-03 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 23 | 211 | 8007 | 8007 |
| 39 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 19 | 19 | 6022 |
| 40 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 6 | 94 | 113 | 6022 |
| 41 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 10 | 48 | 161 | 6022 |
| 42 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 11 | 97 | 258 | 6022 |
| 43 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 12 | 48 | 306 | 6022 |
| 44 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 13 | 39 | 345 | 6022 |
| 45 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 14 | 499 | 844 | 6022 |
| 46 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 15 | 799 | 1643 | 6022 |
| 47 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 16 | 180 | 1823 | 6022 |
| 48 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 17 | 55 | 1878 | 6022 |
| 49 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 18 | 27 | 1905 | 6022 |
| 50 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 19 | 2246 | 4151 | 6022 |
| 51 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 20 | 1518 | 5669 | 6022 |
| 52 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 21 | 247 | 5916 | 6022 |
| 53 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 22 | 106 | 6022 | 6022 |
| 54 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 18 | 18 | 7623 |
| 55 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 6 | 44 | 62 | 7623 |
| 56 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 7 | 51 | 113 | 7623 |
| 57 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 8 | 450 | 563 | 7623 |
| 58 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 9 | 385 | 948 | 7623 |
| 59 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 10 | 469 | 1417 | 7623 |
| 60 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 11 | 254 | 1671 | 7623 |
| 61 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 12 | 1014 | 2685 | 7623 |
| 62 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 13 | 415 | 3100 | 7623 |
| 63 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 14 | 297 | 3397 | 7623 |
| 64 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 15 | 31 | 3428 | 7623 |
| 65 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 17 | 50 | 3478 | 7623 |
| 66 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 18 | 3771 | 7249 | 7623 |
| 67 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 19 | 52 | 7301 | 7623 |
| 68 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 20 | 96 | 7397 | 7623 |
| 69 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 21 | 59 | 7456 | 7623 |
| 70 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 22 | 167 | 7623 | 7623 |
| 71 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 6 | 54 | 54 | 7916 |
| 72 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 7 | 1223 | 1277 | 7916 |
| 73 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 8 | 118 | 1395 | 7916 |
| 74 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 10 | 77 | 1472 | 7916 |
| 75 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 11 | 709 | 2181 | 7916 |
| 76 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 12 | 123 | 2304 | 7916 |
| 77 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 13 | 36 | 2340 | 7916 |
| 78 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 14 | 14 | 2354 | 7916 |
| 79 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 15 | 156 | 2510 | 7916 |
| 80 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 16 | 149 | 2659 | 7916 |
| 81 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 17 | 995 | 3654 | 7916 |
| 82 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 18 | 2022 | 5676 | 7916 |
| 83 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 19 | 34 | 5710 | 7916 |
| 84 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 21 | 937 | 6647 | 7916 |
| 85 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 22 | 1208 | 7855 | 7916 |
| 86 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 23 | 61 | 7916 | 7916 |

Comment: I think you need to go with a custom visual for this. Perhaps the wizard David Bacci will see this post and provide a solution using Deneb!

Comment: My mum always taught me that complements get you everywhere :D.

Comment: Hi @david-bacci ! Thanks for reply. I tried Deneb, but I did not achieve the expected result. Can you help me, please? I will add the sample data to the original post.

Comment: Please mark your previous questions as solved. You will also need to reformat your sample data so it is useable.

Comment: @DavidBacci data is reformated to table Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

Data:

[image]

Add Deneb visual and then add the following fields ensuring that don't summarise is selected for each column.

[image]

[image]

Inside Deneb, paste the following spec.

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "datum['weekday ']<= 5?'weekday':'weekend'",
      "as": "type"
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {"mark": {"type": "point"}},
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "interpolate":"basis"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
         
          "field": "hour"
        },
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "mean",
          "field": "cumulative_daily_steps"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "hour",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"title": "Hour of Day"}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "cumulative_daily_steps",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {
        "title": "Cumulative Step Count"
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "type",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {
        "range": ["red", "green"]
      },
      "legend": {"title": ""}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're a magician. Thank you so much. It's working great. Thank you so much! @DavidBacci

Comment: Good stuff - you're welcome.